# Accessing a member of a "variable" class

Tags: php

A variable named `$class` contains the name of a class.

How can I access a static member of that class?

I need an approach that would work in PHP 5.2.

---

The following works in PHP 5.3:

```
$class::$default_error_message;
```

In PHP 5.2 it outputs:

```
unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

---

Btw, `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`?! PHP doesn't cease to amaze me.

Comment: FYI: "PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM" is apparently Hebrew for "double colon". PHP also defines the parser token `T_DOUBLE_COLON`, as an alias I guess, but the Hebrew version is a well known joke by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getStaticMember($class, $member) {
    if(is_object($class))
        $class = get_class($class);
    $classObj = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $result = null;
    foreach($classObj->getStaticProperties() as $prop => $value) {
        if($prop == $member) {
            $result = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Also:

> [In PHP, the scope resolution operator
>   is also called Paamayim Nekudotayim
>   (Hebrew: פעמיים נקודתיים‎), which
>   means "twice colon" or "double colon"
>   in Hebrew.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)

Answer (score 2):

Use [get_class_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php)

```
$values = get_class_vars($class);

echo $values["default_error_message"];
```

[CodePad Demo](http://codepad.org/U3bWe7bL)

Comment: He's trying to read a static variable, not call a function.

Comment: Very true, changed up the answer.

Comment: I believe `$default_error_message` must be become `"default_error_message"`. Other then that, that's a great approach. Quite elegant.

Comment: That's correct, sorry about that.

Comment: the docs make it sound like `get_class_vars` returns the default values of each variable, which isn't necessarily the same as the current value.  See the example, in which $var2 and $var3 are assigned values in the constructor which are not reflected in the output of the function.